# redirect of a specific URL htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I tried to apply the solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3558590) to redirecting problem. Doesn't seem to work. I'm stumped.

I need to redirect (domain.com/shop/cart.php?m=product_detail&p=7)
to (domain.com/shop/category-page/product-page-c23/).

The code I tried is below:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=product_detail(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)p=7
RewriteRule cart.php /shop/category-page/product-page-c23/
```

I really appreciate any advice that is out there. Thank you. I'll buy you a beer.

Answer (score 0):

There are some minor mistakes in your code. Try this code in .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=product_detail(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)p=7(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^shop/cart\.php/?$ /shop/category-page/product-page-c23/ [NC,L]
```