# redirect different pages to one page

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm putting a search engine on my site, and the search box appears on several different pages. The output looks like this: http://mysite.com/mypage.php?bluepart=search&keywords=dogs&go=Go I'm trying to do an .htaccess mod rewrite to where any page that passes these variables will get redirected to search_results.php. The bluepart=search and go=Go will always be the same, but keywords can be any number or words. Also, some of my pages are .html and some are .php, when I refer to any page that passes the variables.

How do you do this, what does the code look like?

Comment: Why don't you have a form pointing its action to `search_results.php` directly?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558590/htaccess-redirect-for-existence-of-a-specific-url-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't sent any data back yet, you can use the redirect header.

```
if( $_REQUEST['bluepart'] == 'search' && isset($_REQUEST['keywords']) )
    header('Location: http://mysite.com/search_result.php?bluepart=search&keywords=' . $_REQUEST['keywords']);
```

Comment: I can try this, but it needs the "go" variable too. What would that look like? Also just plug this code into the php section at the top of the page? @Jonathan Weatherhead

Comment: Wow, I figured it out. Works great! Thanks for your answer and your help.